# C - some ridiculous bug with file i/o

Tags: c, linux, archlinux

I have a simple program behaving similar to cp, which copies the contents from one file to another, including holes. Simple semantics with simple implementation, main parts of which are given below. The problem is, if I compile it and run (GCC 4.7.1 Arch Linux) without the line, marked below, it fills the second file with random sequence of bytes for a couple of seconds, finishing with a segmentation fault. But if I insert the marked line (which simply outputs to the tty the number of currently written byte - everything is OK). If I use e.g. `printf("Hello World!\n")` instead of it, it's still broken.

What is going on here? How is some library function without any relationship to the semantics of the program causing this error?

```
#include "tlpi_hdr.h" //declares errExit and usageErr
#include <malloc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if ( argc != 3 )
        usageErr("cp_self source dest");
    int fd_source, fd_dest, bytes;
    char *buf, *cur;
    buf = malloc(BUF_SIZE);
    FILE *str;

    if ( ( fd_source = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY) ) == -1 )
        errExit("open(%s)", argv[1]);
    if ( ( fd_dest = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO) ) == -1 )
        errExit("open(%s)", argv[2]);
    if ( ( str = fdopen(fd_dest, "w") ) == NULL )
        errExit("fdopen(%d, 'w')", fd_dest);
    while ( ( bytes = read(fd_source, buf, BUF_SIZE) ) != 0 )
    {
        int dbg_cntr = 0;
        cur = buf;
        while ( cur != buf + bytes )
        {
            //printf("%d\n", dbg_cntr++); this line
            if ( *cur == '\0' )
            {
                if ( fflush(str) != 0 )
                    errExit("fflush(%d)", str);
                if ( lseek(fd_dest, 1, SEEK_CUR) == (off_t) -1 )
                    errExit("lseek(%d, 1, SEEK_CUR)", fd_dest);
            }
            else
            {
                if ( fprintf(str, "%c", *cur) != 1 )
                    errExit("fprintf(%d, %c)", str, *cur);
            }
            ++cur;
        }
    }
}
```

The whole code added.

Comment: Need to see the declarations for cur and buf.  I suspect the problem is that you haven't declared one of them correctly.

Comment: 1) You're not doing *any* error checking: a definite "hello flag". 2) There's *no* protection against pointer "cur" going outside of buffer "buf". Danger, Will Robinson! 3) Exactly *which* line is causing the segmentation violation?  You can determine this by compiling with "gcc -g" and running the program in "gdb".

Comment: @John Bode added declarations.

Comment: @paulsm4 1) error checking is actually done in the program, I just simplified it till the point it still has the same semantics but does not contain code, that is not related to the question. 2) bytes <= BUF_SIZE <= sizeof(buf). So why there is no protection? 3) Will do it in a moment.

Comment: Please post the whole program.  Why would you only post part of it?

Comment: This is a typical error where you write in some memory on the stack where you shouldn't. You should have run valgrind before posting here. Compile your program  with debugging (`-g`) and execute it with valgrind. It will find your error.

Comment: Terribly sorry, I really should have done it before. Problem was in malloc line. Removed it in the beginning of debugging (don't even know now what the problem was then, but it didn't work) and totally forgot about it. Extremely sorry and thanks a lot. Need to cope with valgrind and gdb. Ahhr, damn, sorry, people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call read, `buf` has not been initialized to point to anything in particular so this will give undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

`read()` will return `-1` on error: in this case, `buf + bytes` will be less than `cur` and you will have an infinite loop until `cur` points to some memory which you're not allowed to read, causing a segmentation violation.

Comment: yeah, it caused SIGSEGV, my bad. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

`dbg_cntr++` increments a variable.  I'm not sure what scope it has but it may be affecting other parts of the program.  Try keeping this statement without the `printf`.

Comment: Yes, everything is still OK with simple increment.

Comment: This is why it is a good idea not to modify values in a `print` statement.

Comment: Yeah, but still it's not clear why it influences the behavior of the program.

Comment: what you are experiencing is 'undefined behavior'. Adding lines that should change anything but that do in fact change things is a great clue that you are in 'undefined' land. It means you have uninitialized things, overruns, etc. Another common clue is compiling with different switches makes the bug come and go.